# "The * field is required" when the EF object has the field already

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

My datamodel is the following:

```
[Table("Jobs")]
public abstract class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
}

[Table("PbnJobs")]
public abstract class PbnJob : Job
{
    [Required]
    public virtual PbnSite Site{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Site")]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
}

[Table("DomainJobs")]
public class DomainJob : PbnJob
{
}

public class PbnSite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Site is just a foreign key object.

My code looks the following:

```
var context = new LmDbContext();
var job = context.Jobs.First();
job.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The thing is, the above code throws the exception of type

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException

, saying:

> "The Site field is required"

However when I add:

```
var site = ((PbnJob)job).Site;
```

Making the code:

```
var context = new LmDbContext();
var job = context.Jobs.First();
var site = ((PbnJob)job).Site;
job.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Then the context is saved just fine.

What's the issue here?

EDIT: By the way I'm using proxies and lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark with required attribute simple properties, not navigation properties:

```
[Table("PbnJobs")]
public abstract class PbnJob : Job
{
    public virtual PbnSite Site{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Site")]
    [Required]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
}
```

In this case Required is not useful cause your foreign key property is not nullable.

Comment: I see. So how would I go about my issue?
I mean, like you said, I can't mark the SiteId as required since int isn't nullable.

Comment: Well, because the PbnJob object isn't valid if it doesn't have a Site object.

Comment: It will be required due to not nullable foreign key. Required attribute is unnecessary, you can simlply remove it and all will work as you want.